# cakephp - joining tables

Tags: cakephp

I have a model with associations. Root table is Master_student. Everything else has a foreign key to master_student_ssn

```
<?php

class MasterStudent extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'MasterStudent';
    var $primaryKey = 'ssn';
    var $displayField = 'SSN';
    var $useTable = 'MASTER_STUDENTS';
    var $order = array("ssn" => "asc");




    var $hasMany = array(
        'MasterEmail' => array(
            'className' => 'MasterEmail',
            'foreignKey' => 'master_student_ssn',
            'conditions' => '',
            'order' => 'source',
            'limit' => '',
            'dependent' => true
        ),
        'MasterAddress' => array(
            'className' => 'MasterAddress',
            'foreignKey' => 'master_student_ssn',
            'conditions' => '',
            'order' => 'source',
            'limit' => '',
            'dependent' => true
        ),
        'MasterPhone' => array(
            'className' => 'MasterPhone',
            'foreignKey' => 'master_student_ssn',
            'conditions' => '',
            'order' => 'source',
            'limit' => '',
            'dependent' => true
        ),
        'MasterStudentName' => array(
            'className' => 'MasterStudentName',
            'foreignKey' => 'master_student_ssn',
            'conditions' => '',
            'order' => 'Effective_Date desc,source',
            'limit' => '',
            'dependent' => true
        )
    );

}

?>


 [MASTER_STUDENTS](
    [SSN] [int] NOT NULL,
    [date_student_added] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MASTER_STUDENT] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SSN] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


[MASTER_ADDRESSES](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [master_student_ssn] [int] NOT NULL,
    [address1] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [city] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [state] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [zip] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_master_addresses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

[MASTER_STUDENT_NAMES](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [master_student_ssn] [int] NOT NULL,
    [First_Name] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Middle_Name] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Last_Name] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MASTER_STUDENTS_NAMES] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

How can I use cake's find method such that I can list ALL addresses, phones, names that beling to a person  by searching by a person's

1) Last Name 
2) Phone number

ie. I want all data associated with the model by cake doing a join on these tables.

The code in the MasterStudent Model is

```
 $opts = array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'MasterStudentName.last_name LIKE ' => $searchvalue . '%'
            )
        );
        $this->MasterStudent->recursive = 1;
        $data = $this->MasterStudent->find('all', $opts);
```

The generated query with JohnP's approach is

SELECT [MasterStudent].[SSN] AS [MasterStudent__0], CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), [MasterStudent].[date_student_added], 20) AS [MasterStudent_*1], [MasterStudent].[ssn] AS [MasterStudent*_2], [MasterStudent].[ssn] AS [MasterStudent_*8], [MasterStudent].[ssn] AS [MasterStudent*_19], [MasterStudent].[ssn] AS [MasterStudent_*26], [MasterStudent].[ssn] AS [MasterStudent*_36] 
FROM [MASTER_STUDENTS] AS [MasterStudent] WHERE [MasterStudentName].[Last_name]  = 'Smith'

Comment: Are you really still using PHP 4?

Comment: @Justin, that's just Cake's code generation. It does that to stay compatible

Comment: I'm referring the use of `var` in a PHP class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

A curious way to organize your data, but this should do it.

```
$opts = array(
  'conditions' => array(
     'MasterStudentName.last_name' => 'something', //assuming last name is stored in MasterStudentName
     'MasterPhone.phone' => '23525222'
  )
);
$this->MasterStudent->recursive = 1;
$data = $this->MasterStudent->find('all', $opts);
```

Recursive is set to 1 so it will pull all the associations.

Comment: This query does not pull anything from the Master Student Names table. It does selects all columns from Master Student and fails because it tries to match MasterStudentName.last_name which exists in the Master Student Name table... help!

Comment: I can'y help you unless you put up your DB structure. Just put up the tables in a simple format in your question. _Do not just dump your sql_

Comment: Thanks JohnP, I have edited my original question to represent a simplified table structure

Comment: Looking at your table, I don't see what the problem is. `MasterStudentName` has the `last_name` column and it does a comparison on it. What's the problem?

Comment: I have posted the query and the code. The problem is that MasterStudentName is not selected in the FROM clause.

Comment: And neither are the other tables like MasterPhone , MasterAddress etc.

Comment: try `$this->MasterStudent->recursive = 1; $data = $this->MasterStudent->find('all');` Basically pull all the data from the database without options. If it still doesn't join all your tables then the issue is that your models are not bound properly